# Adding LEFT JOIN add results or modify them

Tags: sql, left-join, aggregate-functions

My tables are designed like that: cours>modules>sections>parts I mean there's courses, inside courses there's modules, inside modules there's sections...

This is my actual query:

```
SELECT PG.idpage,PG.type
                FROM pages PG
                JOIN parts P            ON P.idpart=PG.idpart
                JOIN sections S         ON S.idsection=P.idsection
                JOIN modules M          ON M.idmodule=S.idmodule
                JOIN coursuser CU       ON CU.idcours=M.idcours     
                WHERE PG.idpart='15' AND CU.iduser='1'
                ORDER BY idpage;
```

What I'm trying:

```
SELECT PG.idpage,PG.type,R.time
                FROM pages PG
                JOIN parts P            ON P.idpart=PG.idpart
                JOIN sections S         ON S.idsection=P.idsection
                JOIN modules M          ON M.idmodule=S.idmodule
                JOIN coursuser CU       ON CU.idcours=M.idcours     
                LEFT JOIN reads R   ON R.idpage=PG.idpage   
                WHERE PG.idpart='15' AND CU.iduser='1'
                ORDER BY idpage;
```

I expected to have the same results with just the columns of reads added, but this is not the case, why ?

Comment: Because there are multiple rows in the `reads` table for each `PG.idpage`?

Comment: You aren't selecting any columns from the reads table.

Comment: Sorry I edited, I select R.time

Comment: Joe, yes it must be that, just forgot about that... How can I use the first row only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of which first row you'd want to use from `reads` table.
Normally this is the case for aggregate functions, or some nested subquery.

For example if you wanted to take maximum `time` from `reads` table you would need to add a `GROUP BY` clause and apply an aggregate function retrieving maximum value `MAX(R.time)` from reads table.

```
SELECT PG.idpage, PG.type, MAX(R.time) as time
                FROM pages PG
                JOIN parts P            ON P.idpart=PG.idpart
                JOIN sections S         ON S.idsection=P.idsection
                JOIN modules M          ON M.idmodule=S.idmodule
                JOIN coursuser CU       ON CU.idcours=M.idcours     
                LEFT JOIN reads R   ON R.idpage=PG.idpage   
                WHERE PG.idpart='15' AND CU.iduser='1'
                GROUP BY PG.idpage, PG.type
                ORDER BY idpage;
```

Comment: Yes, this is it. Thanks !